# Interaction variables with percentage/share

Tags: r, regression, interaction, quantiles

Im currently working on a regression model that looks at how the electricity price is impacted by imports of intermittent (wind, solar) electricity from interconnected countries. In the research process I have found that demand is an important factor that may "hide" the effect of intermittent generation especially when demand is high. In addition, due to the price structure of the market, intermittent generation will only have an effect if the generation is large enough. It is always the most expensive generation source that sets the price. If intermittent covers enough of demand it will be a price setter and expensive sources such as gas is not needed.

Therefore I want to include the relationships of all this in my regression. My main approach to investigate my research question is to include intermittent generation in country X and import from country X as an interaction variable. However, now I want to take the abovementioned relationships into account. First I tried to create shares where I took the import divided by the demand to capture the effect and capacity constraints from the interconnector. Then I created a variable which is the share of intermittent production of total production in country X, and then used these two shares as an interaction variable. However, the coefficients gets unrealistically large and im not sure how to interpret this.

To sum up the approach:

> imp_share = import/demand
>
> intermit_share = intermittent/total_prod
>
> y ~ imp_share + intermit_share + imp_share*intermit_share

Do anyone have any suggestion to how I can model this? Or why the coefficients becomes extremely high?

Answer (score 0):

The magnitude of a regression coefficient is related to the measurement scale of the associated continuous predictor. A change of 1 unit in outcome per millimeter change in a predictor is equivalent to a change of $10^{6}$ outcome units per kilometer change in the same predictor.

Without more details about the model it's hard to say if something else is going on in your case. But don't worry about the coefficient magnitudes per se, if they make sense in the overall context of the model.